# Bootstrap 4.5.3 Tooltip placement "auto left" not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" id="email" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!<br>a" data-trigger="focus" data-html="true" data-placement="auto left">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

Tooltip in "**a**" tag is working fine.

But in textboxt combination of "data-placement" not working
I got "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined" while using tooltip with the combination of "***auto left***" in "**input**"

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container mt-3">
    <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
    <p>Tooltips must be initialized with jQuery: select the specified element and call the tooltip() method.</p>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" id="email" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!<br>a" data-trigger="focus" data-html="true" data-placement="auto left">
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Quite a few results [searching for the error](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot+read+property+%27indexOf%27+of+undefined%22+popper+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Remove the `auto` OR `left` from data-placement - _now you can specify only one of `auto | top | bottom | left | right`_